# Access custom Finder labels from a sandboxed app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsworkspace

I have [an app](http://fat-apps.com/videobuffet) which can (among other things) display and change the Finder labels on files. It gets the colors and labels via `NSWorkspace`'s [`finderLabels`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/fileLabels) and [`finderLabelColors`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/fileLabelColors) methods, and it gets and sets the labels on files using `NSURL`'s [`getResourceValue:forKey:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/getResourceValue%3aforKey%3aerror%3a) and [`setResourceValue:forKey:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/setResourceValue%3aforKey%3aerror%3a) methods. This all works fine.

The problem arises when one changes the names of the labels via Finder preferences. I've found that `NSWorkspace`'s [`finderLabels`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/fileLabels) will always give the default names ("Red", "Orange", and so on), rather than whatever custom label name the user has entered.

I found some code in [this project](http://code.google.com/p/fileview/) which does correctly get custom Finder label strings, however it's doing so by accessing Finder preferences (specifically, by calling `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.Labels"]`). Aside from feeling icky, the [NSUserDefaults reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states:

> Sandbox Considerations 
>   A sandboxed app cannot access or modify the preferences for any other app.

My app is sandboxed, so that apparently won't work.

So my question is, why doesn't `NSWorkspace`'s [`finderLabels`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/fileLabels) return custom Finder label strings, and is there some other way that this can be achieved in a sandboxed app?

Comment: finderLabels is working fine for me.None,
    Gray,
    Green,
    Purple,
    Blue,
    Yellow,
    "Red_1",
    "Orange_1"

Comment: @ParagBafna Yes, I see that in a non-Sandboxed app `fileLabels` works for me as well, but it stops working as soon as I turn on App Sandbox.